# merge sum of counts from id in mysql

Tags: mysql

I not mysql expert and I need help to make count query, I need merge sum of count from id 5 and 11 to one count number = 286 and give platform name as GCS in this case.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT (p.id) AS id, (p.name) AS platform,
IFNULL(count(e.id), 0) AS count
FROM event e, lu_platform p
WHERE e.platform_id = p.id
AND p.id NOT IN ( 10, 15, 17, 18 )
AND e.sourcetype_id = 1
AND e.event_datetime BETWEEN '2013-11-4'
AND '2013-11-10' AND e.sender_id  NOT IN ( 759, 73 )
GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY id;

+----+---------------------------+-------+
| id | platform                  | count |
+----+---------------------------+-------+
|  3 | GGG                       |   414 |
|  4 | KIKI                      |   156 |
|  5 | KJC                       |   284 |
|  6 | LOLO                      |     4 |
|  7 | MOD                       |  1147 |
|  8 | MARKT                     |  1049 |
| 11 | GCS                       |     2 |
| 12 | POLAR                     |    30 |
| 14 | GUAE                      |   145 |
+----+---------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: What's the principle? Or it's just some special case?

Comment: it is  just special case, the same I need to do with id 3 and 4

Comment: Then your best shot is to do that in application

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `sub-query`

```
SELECT SUM(count) as count, `GCG` as platform
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT (p.id) AS id, (p.name) AS platform,
    IFNULL(count(e.id), 0) AS count
    FROM event e, lu_platform p
    WHERE e.platform_id = p.id
    AND p.id NOT IN ( 10, 15, 17, 18 )
    AND e.sourcetype_id = 1
    AND e.event_datetime BETWEEN '2013-11-4'
    AND '2013-11-10' AND e.sender_id  NOT IN ( 759, 73 )
    GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY id;
) T
WHERE id IN (5,11)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do it - use a subquery, a sum, 
and IF function, or a case expression CASE WHEN THEN:

```
SELECT sum( case when id in ( 5, 11 ) then count else 0 end ) as count_5_11,
       sum( if( id in ( 3, 4 ), count, 0 ) ) As count_3_4
FROM (
  -- your query goes here
  SELECT DISTINCT (p.id) AS id, (p.name) AS platform,
         IFNULL(count(e.id), 0) AS count
  ....
  ....
  ....
  ....
  ....
) AS some_alias
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reply.
In the both above answers I get only one results instead of list. I think the best way is do this in application as was mentioned by sarwar026.

I noticed also that ISNULL(count(e.id), 0) is not working as I expected, platforms without records not returning 0, they are skipped.